# Ubuntu 16.04.1 : Unity still showing user list on indicator menu

Tags: unity, 16.04, indicator

I have my configuration scripts that hide the user list on the indicator menu on the right.

This was done using by setting the "user-show-menu" key to false in the 
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.indicator.session.gschema.xml 
file.

This no longer seems to be taking effect, I'm wondering what changed.
I tried this on both using my script (which replaces the xml file with the one already configured) and editing the existing file.

This works in 16.04

Did I miss something? 
-yes, I did:

- I was using gsettings from the root account with no effect on the user that was logged in, or any other users for that matter.
- updating the xml file in the directory works but only if  `glib-compile-schemas` is called on the schemas directory.

-C

Answer (score 3):

It is not the best option to edit the xml file.

The proper way to hide users is to open the terminal and type the following command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session user-show-menu false
```

Enter your password

[image]

Comment: TheXed, thanks for replying the two 16.04.1 machines I have arn't responding to the command. Are you running 16.04.1 and if so, was it upgraded or installed from scratch?